# How to use binding in Django Raw SQL

Tags: python, sql, django, oracle

How can I use a single variable to binding in more than one filter in Django SQL?

What I want:

I defined the variable: date

I want to use the same information in the SQL WHERE Clausures: CUR_DATE, ACHIEVED_DATE

```
def kpiMonitoring(self):
    with connections['db'].cursor()as cursor:
        import time
        date = time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
       
        cursor.execute("""        
        SELECT *  FROM TABLE1
        WHERE CUR_DATE = date
              AND ACHIEVED_DATE = date

        """,[date])
        row = dictfetchall(cursor)
        cursor.close()
        return row
```

I can do it by this way, but this solution is not scalable:

```
def kpiMonitoring(self):
        with connections['db'].cursor()as cursor:
            import time
            date = time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
            date2 = date
           
            cursor.execute("""        
            SELECT *  FROM TABLE1
            WHERE CUR_DATE = %s
                  AND ACHIEVED_DATE = %s
    
            """,[date, date2])
            row = dictfetchall(cursor)
            cursor.close()
            return row
```

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Why use raw queries in the first place? One of the main reasons to use a Django ORM, is that an ORM queries is often syntactically much shorter, than using a raw query.

Comment: You're correct, but is this case I don't have enough authorization in database to use with Django ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform such query with a named parameter:

```
cursor.execute(
    '''SELECT *  FROM TABLE1
       WHERE CUR_DATE = %(date)s
         AND ACHIEVED_DATE = %(date)s''',
    {'date': date }
)
```

another solution is to simply check if the `CUR_DATE` is the same as the `ACHIEVED_DATE` and thus use the parameter only once:

```
cursor.execute(
    '''SELECT *  FROM TABLE1
       WHERE CUR_DATE = %s
         AND ACHIEVED_DATE = CUR_DATE''',
    [date]
)
```

but regardless, using raw queries is not a good idea. It often, as you found out yourself, does not scale very well (making use of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s is usually shorter with the Django ORM), and usually it is less error prone, and less sensitive for database migrations.

Comment: Thank you @Willem Van Onsem, It worked nice, I'll improve it according your suggestion!